# fileevent and after in same event loop

Tags: tcl

To parse a log file I want to do something like this

- tail the file
- after some time write parsed data and do other things

Here is my (sample) script

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh

proc readfile {fd} {
    while {[gets $fd line] >= 0} {
        puts $line
    }
}

proc writefile {} {
    puts xxx
    flush stdout
}

if {$::argc > 0} {
    set fd [open [list | tail --follow=name --retry [lindex $argv 0] 2>@1]]
} else {
    set fd stdin
}

after 3000 writefile

fileevent $fd readable [list readfile $fd]

vwait done
close $fd
```

Tailing works fine but the script for `after` isn't triggered.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In the `readfile` proc, you are using a `while` which causing it to get stuck in it and that is why the `after`  is not triggered.

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh

proc readfile {fd} {
   global done
   puts "READ FILE CALLED..."
   gets $fd line; # Removed 'while' loop here
   puts "->>>>$line<<<<<<<<<"

   ### Your condition to exit the event handler#### 
   ### set done 1; #### Changing 'done' value to 1 after that condition ####
   ### So that the event handler will exit ####3
}

proc writefile {} {
    puts "WRITE FILE CALLED"
    puts xxx
    flush stdout
}

if {$::argc > 0} {
    set fd [open [list | tail --follow=name --retry [lindex $argv 0] 2>@1]]
} else {
    set fd stdin
}

after 3000 writefile

fileevent $fd readable [list readfile $fd]

vwait done
close $fd
```

**Output :**

```
dinesh@dinesh-VirtualBox:~/pgms/tcl$ ./ubi.tcl 
WRITE FILE CALLED
xxx
ubi
READ FILE CALLED...
->>>>ubi<<<<<<<<<
cool
READ FILE CALLED...
->>>>cool<<<<<<<<<
working 
READ FILE CALLED...
->>>>working <<<<<<<<<
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise fileevent would be called everytime when there's a new line available. What happens if there are multiple lines available? Does `readline` get called multiple times or it reads only one line without the `while` loop?

Comment: @ubi : It will be called each time.